# IOS retain a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How can i go from a uitabbarcontroller to a viewcontroller in fullscreen, retaining all the data and views/tabs on the uitabbarcontroller?

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to hide the TabBar or show a new view, but once you're done with the new view have the TabBar be unaffected?

In the case of the latter try something like:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWith...];
[self presentModalViewController:vc];
```

Comment: In this case, I want to go from a tabbar where i have some thumbnails of photos, and i've information in the other tabs that I want to retain. And i want to go to a fullscreen view to see the photos in fullscreen.

Comment: In that case, I think a modal view is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add ViewController on TabBar in fullScreen then:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController " bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Now dissmiss that Modal Controller like this in any event( of button may be)

```
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

After this your tabbar will as it is:

Comment: By the way, in iOS 5, you might want to use presentViewController and dismissViewControllerAnimated as the modal versions are deprecated.

Comment: Is there any method to put on the viewWillUnload, to retain that view? I just want to retain my views, when i change the vc :S